# PDO Insert / Update on duplicate key

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert-update

I have information coming from an online form, anywhere from 1-12 rows of repeated fields.  It's all working up to this point, but when there is a duplicate, I'd like it to update three columns.

I'm having a hard time finding a solution for this:

```
$player = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO a_players(schoolID,nameFirst,nameLast,feet,inches,grade,position,varsity) 
    VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    feet = :feet
    inches = :inches
    varsity = :varsity
    ");
    $player->bind_param('ssssssss',$schoolID,$fname,$lname,$feet,$inches,$grade,$position,$varsity);   <-- Line 55
```

Here is the error being thrown:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in /home2/csi/public_html/wp-content/plugins/csi_stats/csi_roster_form_process.php:55 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home2/csi/public_html/wp-content/plugins/csi_stats/csi_roster_form_process.php on line 55

I have tried adding to Line 55 additional sss and additional variables.

I have tried adding separate bindparam lines. I keep getting the same error.  I'm not understanding how to bind variables to

Comment: I'm sorry but this code makes no sense. You are mixing PDO and mysqli. Please take some time to learn the basic syntax of PDO https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Comment: I got some of it off of "answers" on here, and up to the Duplicate Key Update part it worked.  I just wanted to add that to it.

Comment: The error is occurring on the call to `prepare ()` because there is a syntax error in your SQL. You're missing commas between the entries in your`UPDATE` values list. You're not checking for that so the first error you see is when the `bind` fails.

Comment: Thank you!  

(From there I had to add more parameters and variables to match the placeholders.)

Comment: @Dharman I have the resource you linked for me before (the last couple of days), and I didn't know there was a difference between bind_param and bindparam.  I'll dig in and alter the code, accordingly.  It's just good to know it works.

Comment: Yes, also I believe you can't mix positional and named placeholders

Comment: Yeah, I read that and changed it.  That and adding commas got it to work, despite mixing my bind_param format.

Answer (score 0):

You had a mixture of mysqli and pdo.

This is a pdo example.

```
<?php

$player = $con->prepare('
  Inser Into
    a_players
  Set
    schoolID   = :schoolID,
    nameFirst  = :nameFirst,
    nameLast   = :nameLast,
    feet       = :feet,
    inches     = :inches,
    grade      = :grade,
    position   = :position,
    varsity    = :varsity
  On Duplicate Key Update
    feet       = :feet2
    inches     = :inches2
    varsity    = :varsity2
');

$player->execute([
  ':schoolID' => $schoolID,
  ':fname'    => $fname,
  ':lname'    => $lname,
  ':feet'     => $feet,
  ':inches'   => $inches,
  ':grade'    => $grade,
  ':position' => $position,
  ':varsity'  => $varsity,
  ':feet2'    => $feet,
  ':inches2'  => $inches,
  ':varsity2' => $varsity,
]);
```

Comment: Part of my issue too, as I understand it, was mixing positional and named placeholders, which you evidently can't do.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $player = $con->prepare('Insert Into a_players
    (schoolID, nameFirst  , nameLast ,feet, inches, grade, position, varsity)
    values
    (:schoolID,:nameFirst,:nameLast, :feet, :inches, :grade,:position,:varsity)
    On Duplicate Key Update
   feet       = :feet2
   inches     = :inches2
   varsity    = :varsity2
   ');
      $player->execute([
              ':schoolID' => $schoolID,
              ':fname'    => $fname,
              ':lname'    => $lname,
              ':feet'     => $feet,
              ':inches'   => $inches,
              ':grade'    => $grade,
              ':position' => $position,
              ':varsity'  => $varsity,
              ':feet2'    => $feet,
              ':inches2'  => $inches,
              ':varsity2' => $varsity
              ]);
```

Comment: i add this PHP script because i try multiple answers about update after insert fail on primary key duplicate , and do this in only one query , i change answer by @Jason K , where its not work for me and give sql error, note: you do not need to add primary key on update as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If we look at the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php), then we see that it either returns a [PDOStatement](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php) or `false`. You received a `false`, which is a boolean, which means that preparing the statement was unsuccessful. I see two main problems:

- you pass 7 params to the `insert`, but 8 `'` to the `values`
- you are inconsistent with the parameters, you use both question marks and named parameters, I have never tried that, but even if this is syntactically correct, even then you should either only use named parameters or only question marks for the sake of consistency